# show Greek letter in the label of plots by referring to a vector

Tags: r, label

The below code is a simplified one in help file of plotmath. Greek letter "phi" is shown correctly in plot's title.

```
x <- seq(-4, 4, len = 101)
y <- cbind(sin(x), cos(x))

matplot(x, y, type = "l", xaxt = "n",
        main = expression(
          paste(sin * phi,
                "  and  ",
                cos * phi))
)
```

I tried to refer to "phi" which is saved in a vector of "myList", but "phi" is not shown as Greek letter. How can I fix it?

```
myList <- c("phi")

matplot(x, y, type = "l", xaxt = "n",
        main = expression(
          paste(sin * myList[1],
                "  and  ",
                cos * phi)),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
myList <- expression(phi)

matplot(x, y, type = "l", xaxt = "n",
    main = bquote(sin * .(myList[[1]]) ~ " and " ~cos * phi)
)
```

The main thing is that you need to return an expression. You cannot mix strings like "phi" into an expression and expect them to turn into their expression counterpart. Here `bquote` helps us build an expression by allowing us to insert the value from `myList` with the `.()` syntax.

And note that if you want to add other elements to your `myList`, you would use

```
myList <- expression(phi, beta)

matplot(x, y, type = "l", xaxt = "n",
    main = bquote(sin * .(myList[[2]]) ~ " and " ~cos * phi)
)
```

An expression is already vector/list-like as it's really a collection of calls or symbols.

Comment: MrFlick, thanks! Your method works great. I want to expand my question a little more. In the above 'myList', 'phi' is directy entered in 'expression'. If it is a vector 'myList <- c("phi")', is there any method to convert it to 'expression'?

Comment: You'd have to `parse(text=)` it. I'd try to stay away from that if possible.